# Extjs hidden closeTooltip for viewport with setZIndex

Tags: javascript, extjs, tooltip, z-index

I use ExtJS and have viewport which I want to be always on top. I use:

```
setZIndex: function(index) {
var me = this;
me.callParent([1000000]);
return index;}
```

And it works, but I have problem with window close tool tip, which is behind window. It looks like this:

[image: ]]

I have no idea how to fix it. Any suggestions how to move it to front?

Comment: Why you are using z index for viewport ?

Comment: Please share fiddle because I can not able to reproduce it.